# RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered in training LayoutLM

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, training-data

I am trying to train the **LayoutLM** model with a **custom receipt** dataset. However, when training the model, I have encountered  this error:

```
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1603729138878/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:658: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [160,0,0], thread: [125,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1603729138878/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:658: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [160,0,0], thread: [126,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1603729138878/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:658: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [160,0,0], thread: [127,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
Iteration:   2%|▋                               | 3/140 [00:01<01:25,  1.61it/s]
Epoch:   0%|                                              | 0/1 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_seq_labeling.py", line 832, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_seq_labeling.py", line 725, in main
    args, train_dataset, model, tokenizer, labels, pad_token_label_id
  File "run_seq_labeling.py", line 240, in train
    outputs = model(**inputs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/layoutlm/modeling/layoutlm.py", line 224, in forward
    head_mask=head_mask,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/layoutlm/modeling/layoutlm.py", line 178, in forward
    input_ids, bbox, position_ids=position_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/layoutlm/modeling/layoutlm.py", line 102, in forward
    + token_type_embeddings
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

This code was ran on a **[Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/jimuelservandil/fine-tune-layoutlm-using-scanned-receipt-dataset)** environment, with **GPU P100** turned on. What is causing the error? This code works on the **SROIE** dataset, however in the SROIE dataset, there are only **4 labels**, while in this code, we increased it to **8 labels**.

Comment: This is most likely not an environment problem. You may have an inconsistency between the number of labels and output units. Make sure you correctly increased the labels everywhere

Comment: I tried to add some print statements: Epoch:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Iteration:   0% 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Number of Output Units: 9

Num of Labels: 9
Warning: labels index out of range: -100
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:658: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [86,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
     Based on the print statements, the output units and labels have the same value. Does it mean that the problem is not on the labels?